# Convert string to time in HIVE SQL

Tags: hiveql

I have CSV file that has a date and a time field. In HIVE the date and time are strings.
I need to convert the string into a time but I just cannot find a solution.
The output for whatever I try is NULL. I simply want the a aibt time field to be a timestamp and not a string.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue but creating a new date/timestamp with time and date and then using cast to convert it.
CAST(concat(concat_ws(' ',[string date as yyyy-MM-dd],[string time as hh:mm]),':00.0') AS TIMESTAMP) AS new_timestamp